# Sharepoint 2013 Foundation - How To Change From Task To Custom List?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

Recently I have migrated from WSS3.0 to SP2013F and used Microsoft Access to export and import Task & List.

There is a request from end user to change from Task to Customer List. I tried to search the internet for solution but found none.

Is there a way to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple links that i found: [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24896908/Convert-Sharepoint-Custom-list-to-Task-List.html) or [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-a-SharePoint-task-list-into-an-enterprise-project-d1387254-9478-4d9d-90d7-a4aee16b1f3c)